# two similar python codes, one doesn't work

Tags: python, loops

I am new to python and trying to do a finger exercise involving finding roots to an integer.  My first (after many trials and errors) attempt was the following:

```
x = int(raw_input("Please pick a positive integer: "))
root = 2
pwr = 2
while pwr < 6:   #this is meant to change pwr from 2 to 3 to 4 to 5
    if root ** pwr < x and root ** pwr != x:
        pwr = pwr + 1
    elif root ** pwr == ax:
        break
    elif root ** pwr > x:  #increments root to cycle thru again
        root = root + 1
        pwr = 2
if root ** pwr == x:
     print root, '**', pwr, '=', x   
else:
    print x, "has no integer roots."
```

This worked for 8 & 9, but got hung up with 10.

My second attempt worked for all three numbers:

```
x = int(raw_input("Please pick an integer: "))
root = 2
for pwr in range(2,6):
    while root ** pwr < abs(x):
        root = root + 1
        if root ** pwr == abs(x):
            break
    if root ** pwr == abs(x):
        break
        root = root + 1
    root = 2
if root ** pwr == abs(x):
    print root, '**', pwr, '=', x    
else:
    print x, "has no integer roots."
```

Why does the first one get hung up?  I feel I have a basic misunderstanding of how while loops work.  Please help.

Comment: what is it suppose to do?

Comment: What is "ax" ? Your stop condition is "root ** pwr == ax" and in the first case, it is never fullfilled.

Comment: The two programs are very different.

Comment: Your comments show some serious misunderstandings. For example, why would `while pwr < 6` change the value of `pwr`? It is a simple comparison, and you can answer it without mutating anything. You must change `pwr` yourself within the loop, or else the loop will be infinite.

Comment: I have the feeling that the first one doesn't hit an exit condition. Do a `print(pwr)` right after `while pwr < 6` and see what that gives you.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting stuck in

```
    elif root ** pwr > x:  #increments root to cycle thru again
        root = root + 1
        pwr = 2
```

if `root ** 2 > x` setting `pwr = 2` in every iteration.

You need to break the loop somehow if `root` gets to big.

Answer (score 0):

The hang up here in the while loop is because of a couple things, I think.

First, as @Baart mentioned above, `ax` isn't defined--do you mean `x` there?

Second, with 10 as your x, the loop executes as follows:

1. root=2, pwr=2: 2**2 == 4, 4 < 10, so increase pwr
2. root=2, pwr=3: 2**3 == 8, 8 < 10, so increase pwr (this is where it breaks for x == 8)
3. root=2, pwr=4: 2**4 == 16, 16 > 10, so increase root and pwr = 2
4. root=3, pwr=2: 3**2 == 9, 9 < 10, so increase pwr (this is where it breaks for x == 9)
5. root=3, pwr=3: 3**3 == 27, 27 > 10 so increase root and pwr = 2
6. root=4, pwr=2: 4**2 == 16, 16 > 10 so increase root and pwr = 2

and from there, it will increase root into infinity without increasing pwr, while root ** pwr will remain > 10, and thus never meet your break condition.